# Parsing JSON data with LOOP

Tags: json, postgresql, loops, parsing

I am parsing data from JSON with UNION ALL, but I need repeated it more times. Try to use LOOP, but it doesn't works. :(

I need to parse every element from array in JSON to rows from statements.
I change the number of element in: statements::json->0 and than UNION the data.

The CODE I want to replace with some LOOP:

```
(  
  SELECT
    execution_entry_id,
    account,
    trim('"' FROM (account::json->'startBalance')::text) AS startBalance,
    trim('"' FROM (account::json->'endBalance')::text) AS endBalance
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      execution_entry_id,
      statements::json->0 AS account
    FROM(
      SELECT
        e.id AS execution_entry_id,
        response_body,
        response_body::json->'statements' AS statements
      FROM stage_cz.cb_data_execution_entry e
      LEFT JOIN stage_cz.cb_data_execution_entry_details d
      ON d.execution_entry_id = e.id
      WHERE provider_name = 'sokordiatech'
    ) a
  ) b WHERE account IS NOT NULL
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT
    execution_entry_id,
    account,
    trim('"' FROM (account::json->'startBalance')::text) AS startBalance,
    trim('"' FROM (account::json->'endBalance')::text) AS endBalance
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      execution_entry_id,
      statements::json->1 AS account
    FROM(
      SELECT
        e.id AS execution_entry_id,
        response_body,
        response_body::json->'statements' AS statements
      FROM stage_cz.cb_data_execution_entry e
      LEFT JOIN stage_cz.cb_data_execution_entry_details d
      ON d.execution_entry_id = e.id
      WHERE provider_name = 'sokordiatech'
    ) a
  ) b WHERE account IS NOT NULL
)
```

I try to use:

```
do $$
declare 
   counter integer := 0;
begin
   while counter < 10 loop
     SELECT 
      execution_entry_id,
      statements::json->counter AS account
    FROM(
      SELECT
        e.id AS execution_entry_id,
        response_body,
        response_body::json->'statements' AS statements
      FROM stage_cz.cb_data_execution_entry e
      LEFT JOIN stage_cz.cb_data_execution_entry_details d
      ON d.execution_entry_id = e.id
      WHERE provider_name = 'sokordiatech'
    ) a;
      counter := counter + 1;
   end loop;
end$$;
```

and it ends with error:

```
ERROR: query has no destination for result data
  Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at SQL statement
1 statement failed.
```

It's possible to get data with LOOP or how instead of 10x UNION ALL, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are use `statements::json->0`, so you have Json array in your Json string. For splitting array elements from Json array, you can use `jsonb_array_elements_text` function on PostgreSQL, this function will be extracting your array elements like as rows. For do this you don't need using loop. For example:

```
with tbl as (
select 
'[
    {
        "employee_id": 2,
        "full_name": "Megan Berry",
        "manager_id": 1
    },
    {
        "employee_id": 3,
        "full_name": "Sarah Berry",
        "manager_id": 1
    },
    {
        "employee_id": 4,
        "full_name": "Zoe Black",
        "manager_id": 1
    },
    {
        "employee_id": 5,
        "full_name": "Tim James",
        "manager_id": 1
    },
    {
        "employee_id": 6,
        "full_name": "Bella Tucker",
        "manager_id": 2
    }
]'::jsonb as jsondata 
)
select jsondata->1 from tbl;

Result: 
{"full_name": "Sarah Berry", "manager_id": 1, "employee_id": 3}
```

This is getting second element of Json array.
But you need all elements, for getting all elements and extracting key values use this syntax:

```
with table1 as (
select 
'[
    {
        "employee_id": 2,
        "full_name": "Megan Berry",
        "manager_id": 1
    },
    {
        "employee_id": 3,
        "full_name": "Sarah Berry",
        "manager_id": 1
    },
    {
        "employee_id": 4,
        "full_name": "Zoe Black",
        "manager_id": 1
    },
    {
        "employee_id": 5,
        "full_name": "Tim James",
        "manager_id": 1
    },
    {
        "employee_id": 6,
        "full_name": "Bella Tucker",
        "manager_id": 2
    }
]'::jsonb as jsondata 
)
select 
    tb1.a1->>'full_name' as fullname, 
    tb1.a1->>'manager_id' as managerid, 
    tb1.a1->>'employee_id' as employeeid 
from (
    select jsonb_array_elements_text(jsondata)::jsonb as a1 from table1
) tb1

Result: 
fullname        managerid   employeeid
Megan Berry     1           2
Sarah Berry     1           3
Zoe Black       1           4
Tim James       1           5
Bella Tucker    2           6
```